# conditional vectorization with numpy, How to add list to dataframe cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have two dataframes merged together, with two filled columns of integers and a third column with empty lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['z','x','c','v','b','n'], 'col2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['z','x','c','v','b','n'], 'col2': [10, 20, 300, 40, 50, 600]})   
df['col3'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
df1['col3'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

df2 = df.merge(df1, on='col1', how='outer')
```

which yields this

```
     col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y col3_y
0    z      10     []      63     []
1    x      24     []    1365     []
2    c     642     []     356     []
3    v     462     []       2     []
4    b    2454     []     467     []
5    n      23     []      23     []
```

I want to make some calculations if the conditions are correct, and if they are, add a value to each list in `df2['col3_y']`.

```
condition = [
    ((df2['col2_y'] != df2['col2_x']) & (len(df2['col3_y']) < 1)),
    ((df2['col2_y'] != df2['col2_x']) & (len(df2['col3_y']) > 0))
]
action = [
    (df2['col2_y'] - df2['col2_x'])/1000,
    df2['col3_y'] + [(df2['col2_y'] - df2['col2_x'] - sum(df2['col3_y']))/1000]
]

df2['col3_y'] = np.select(condition, action)
```

But it throws me an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'.

**EXPECTED**

For each cell in the list column, `if len(list) > 1` in the same index take the values of `df['col2_y']` subtract from it the values of `df['col2_x']` divide by 1000, and append the solution to the list,
`elif len(list) > 0` in the same index take the values of `df['col2_y']` subtract from it the values from `df2['col2_x']` subtract the sum of the list `df2['col3_y']` divide by 1000 and append the solution to the list.
and if the values in `df2['col2_x'] == df2['col2_y']` do nothing.

```
  col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y    col3_y
0    z     100     []      10     [-0.09]
1    x     200     []      20     [-0.18]
2    c     300     []     300     []
3    v     400     []      40     [-0.36]
4    b     500     []      50     [-0.45]
5    n     600     []     600     []
```

Comment: There are many weird things in your code. For example `(len(df2['col3_y']) < 0)` will always be `False`, len is always ≥ 0. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to check if the list in each cell is empty or not, sorry didn't even realize till now that it cant be less than zero, lets assume its ``==0`` for each cell if the list of integers is empty append to the list the first action, if its not empty append the second action on each cell, sorry if its confusing

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to correct your code. It will go with option1 as all your lists are initially empty. If you apply it once more if will use the initial value for option2. If this is not what you want, **please provide the expected output**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code entirely to use a different solution:

```
df2['col3_y'] = df2.apply(lambda x: np.append(x['col3_y'],
                                             (x['col2_y']-x['col2_x']-x['col3_y'].sum())/1000)
                                    if x['col2_y']!=x['col2_x']
                                    else x['col3_y'],
                          axis=1)
```

output after 1 iteration:

```
  col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y    col3_y
0    z      10     []      63   [0.053]
1    x      24     []    1365   [1.341]
2    c     642     []     356  [-0.286]
3    v     462     []       2   [-0.46]
4    b    2454     []     467  [-1.987]
5    n      23     []      23        []
```

output after 3 iterations:

```
  col1  col2_x col3_x  col2_y                                           col3_y
0    z      10     []      63          [0.053, 0.052947, 0.052894052999999996]
1    x      24     []    1365  [1.341, 1.3396590000000002, 1.3383193409999998]
2    c     642     []     356        [-0.286, -0.285714, -0.28542828600000003]
3    v     462     []       2                   [-0.46, -0.45954, -0.45908046]
4    b    2454     []     467                [-1.987, -1.985013, -1.983027987]
5    n      23     []      23                                               []
```

Comment: Well it's certainly a solution, but do you think it's impossible to do it with numpy vectorization and maintain the performance benefits over lamda?

Comment: Well, the thing is that you have to merge your calculation at come point and this will require looping/applying. I think the best might be to go for a full numpy solution. Do not care about the x==y thing and check this at the end.

Comment: Alright then, Thanks again for the help I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is `sum(df2['col3_y'])`. `sum` requires a list of numbers, and you have a list of lists.

```
>>> sum([1,2])
3
>>> sum([[],[]])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: But how can I make it work, I didn't want to check the sum of all the lists, I'm trying to do the checking for each cell to see if the list is empty or not, and append a calculation accordingly

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: oh man thanks! just finished posting the expected output, I guess you figured it, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: It's not appending tho if there's a number already, it's rewriting it

Comment: As your question has evolved from "what is wrong in my code" to "how do I calculate (…)", I rewrote entirely the code and provided it as another answer. I'll clean this one a bit to keep only the initial answer that is why you had your error in the first place.